# Proving a "well-known" result regarding the distribution of a normally distributed random variable

Tags: normal-distribution, proof, bivariate, truncation

In an important project work, I would like to include a "proof" of the following, but have unfortunately been unable to readily compute it myself. I am aware that this is a flaw on my part, but sincerely hope that you will help me anyway.
If any more  information is needed (I try to supply what i think is relevant), please do not hesitate to ask. Thanks in advance for any and all help!

$\tilde{y}$ is a noisy signal regarding $\tilde{\mu}$, defined as $\tilde{y}=\tilde{\mu}+\tilde{\varepsilon}$ where $\tilde{\varepsilon}$ is a zero-mean normally distributed noise term, with variance $\frac{1}{s}$, and $\tilde{\mu}$ is normally distributed with mean $y_{0}$ and variance $\frac{1}{h_{0}}$.

The realization of $\tilde{y}$, denoted $y$, is unobserved, but we are instructed that it is equal to or below some arbitrary level $H$.

Given this information, the price of an asset is given by:
$$P(\tilde{y}=y\leq H)=E(\tilde{\mu}\mid\tilde{y}=y\leq H)-\beta(var(\tilde{\mu}\mid\tilde{y}=y\leq H))$$
Where $\beta$ is simply a continuous, non-negative, and non-decreasing function of its argument.

Under these conditions I would like a proof that this term is the same as: $$P(\tilde{y}=y\leq H)=y_{0}-\frac{h_{0}^{^{-1}}g(H)}{G(H)}-\beta(k(H))$$
Where $$g(H)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sqrt{\frac{sh_{0}}{h_{0+s}}}exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\frac{sh_{0}}{h_{0+s}}(H-y_{0})^{2}\right]$$
And $$G(H)=\int_{-\infty}^{H}g(t)dt$$

And $$k(H)=h_{0}^{-1}-\frac{s}{h_{0+s}}(H-y_{0})\frac{h_{0}^{-1}g(H)}{G(H)}-\left\{ \frac{h_{0}^{-1}g(H)}{G(H)}\right\} ^{2}$$

I have an inkling that I actually want to use particular results regarding the truncated bivariate normal distribution, but have not been able to realize which and how.